# processing memory game delay

Tags: processing, delay

Hello I'm working on a memory game in processing and need to make the same pair dissappear after some time for example 1 second. Because now its dissappearing instantly. Here is the part when it dissappears

```java
if (fv[cardUp[0]] == fv[cardUp[1]]){
  myCard[cardUp[0]].matched();
  myCard[cardUp[1]].matched();
  win +=1;
}
```

and here is the dissappearing

```java
void matched(){
  cardX = -150;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `millis()` function to record when something happened by storing that value in a variable. Then just check that variable against the current `millis()` to determine whether the delay has elapsed or not.

Here's a simple example that shows an ellipse for 1 second every time the user clicks:

```java
int timeClicked = - 10000;

void draw() {
  if (mousePressed) {
    timeClicked = millis();
  }

  background(0);

  if (millis() < timeClicked + 1000) {
    ellipse(50, 50, 50, 50);
  }
}
```

On a side note, it's hard to answer general "how do I do this" type questions. It's much easier to answer "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. So I'd recommend starting with my small example, trying something out, and posting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck.